# Add computedObservable to existing javascript view model

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have the following ViewModel.

```
function PageSectionVM(pageSection) {
    var self = this;
    self.SectionName = ko.observable();
    self.Markup = ko.observable();

    self.update(pageSection);
}
```

and I have also created the update method as called in the above constructor function.

```
PageSectionVM.prototype.update = function (pageSection) {
    var self = this;
    pageSection = pageSection || {};

    self.SectionName(pageSection.SectionName);
    self.Markup(pageSection.Markup);
};
```

This is bundled off in its own file and I would like to reuse this VM in several pages. On one particular page I would like to 'extend' this viewmodel to include a new function. I have tried do this by adding a new function to PageSectionVM's prototype, like so.

```
PageSectionVM.prototype.tabName = function () {
    var self = this;
    return "#tab-" + self.SectionName();
};
```

If I then add this as a knockout binding statement, it returns the text of the function as opposed to the function result. I get the feeling I am missing something. If I add `tabName` as a computedObservable in the original viewmodel it works, but that means I am putting specific code for a single purpose in my 'general' viewmodel's code (something I'd like to avoid).

The knockout binding statement I am using is

```
<a data-bind="attr:{href: tabName}, text:SectionName"></a>
```

This sits inside a foreach binding on an observableArray of PageSectionVMs. The text property is fine, but the href ends up containing the literal text of the function, not its result.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I then add this as a knockout binding statement, it returns the text of the function as opposed to the function result.

Of course it does. Knockout bindings work like this:

- check if the bound value is an observable
- if yes, unwrap it (i.e. *"execute it"*)
- convert to string what remains and use it in your view

NB: All observables are functions, but not all functions are observables.

That means you will get the function text if your binding looks like `text: SectionName` when `SectionName()` is a plain old function.

Because of the way observables work (w/r/t dependency tracking & `this` handling) you cannot use them in a prototype, they *have* to live in the instance.

That means:

- either you put them in the instance (like @WayneEllery suggests)
- or you call them yourself in the view (`text: SectionName()`)
- or you use `ko.utils.extend()` to extend pre-existing `PageSectionVM` instances with extra observables/computeds.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, very clarifying :) From your reply it sounds like I should be going down the route of ko.utils.extend(). I'm going to look into that now.

Comment: Well, you can use any way you like to slap new properties onto an existing object. `ko.utils.extend()` is just a convenience method, like jQuery's `.extend()`. You could also make a wrapper viewmodel that contains an instance of `PageSectionVM`. Or you write `PageSectionVM`'s constructor in a way that it recognizes what kind of arguments you give it and build different objects depending on that. Or you use KO's mapping plugin to make the constructor fully dynamic.

Comment: Thanks very much for the help .. I have gone down the route of a wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you have a problem using a computed. If you want to use prototype you can do it as follows:

I've also added url encoding and initilized the model.

```
function PageSectionVM(pageSection) {
    var self = this;
    self.SectionName = ko.observable(pageSection.SectionName);
    self.Markup = ko.observable(pageSection.Markup);    
    self.TabName = ko.computed(this.getTabName, self);
};

PageSectionVM.prototype.getTabName = function () {
    var self = this;
    return "#tab-" + encodeURIComponent(self.SectionName());
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5vUhe/

Comment: I don't have a problem using a computed. In fact it makes the most sense, but I couldn't get it to work UNLESS I added the computed to PageSectionVM. But as I stated in my question I'm trying not to add a computed that only makes sense for one use case to the PageSectionVM that I want to use across a range of use cases. So in short I'm trying to extend the PageSectionVM to have an additional computed for one use case. Does that make more sense? I only went down the route of prototype to try and solve the issue in another way.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using inheritance

Comment: Oddly enough I went down that route and ran into issues. I'll go back through my repo and find the checkin where I was experimenting with that. If nothing else this is teaching how little I know about javascript under the hood .. and how quickly I'm loving it.